# Convert a date string of format 'March 12 2019 9:30 am '+ given offset to browser timezone without using any libraries

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

I am getting a date string in this format - 'March 12 2019 11:30 pm' and also the offset in hours like +5.5. I want to convert this date into my browser timezone.

I have tried the following code

```
function convertToLocalTime(date, offset) {
  const serverTime = new Date(date);
  const localOffset = offset * 3600000;
  const d = new Date(serverTime.getTime() + localOffset).toUTCString();
  return new Date(d);
}
```

But I am getting the date as `Tue Mar 12 2019 15:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` which is wrong.

The expected result should be if the date is March 12 2019 11:30 pm and the offset given is -8 and my local time has an offset of +5.5, I should get the date as March 13 2019 12:00 pm.

`convertToLocalTime('March 12 2019 11:30 pm', -8)` 
should give the date as March 13 2019 12:00 pm.

Comment: By saying "without using any libraries", you're asking either for 1) an answer that is implementation dependent (could vary across browsers, platforms, etc.), or 2) for us to write library-like code for you.  Basically, you need to transform your input values into a single string before parsing `new Date("2019-03-12T23:30:00+05:30")` - because that is the only format that is required by the ECMAScript spec.  I'm sure I could bang out such code to manipulate your strings, but why not just use a library that's already tested and widely used? There are many to pick from.

Comment: So my application has a size constraint. So adding moment library will will increase the application size by 100kb. So I cannot use such libraries. The input format is I am passing is accepted by the Date function. When it comes to timezone conversion I am getting the wrong date

Comment: It's actually not accepted by the standard, you're just finding that a particular implementation doesn't reject it. You have no guarantees overall. Also, have you tried other libraries like Luxon or Date-fns? They are both much smaller than Moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
function convertToLocalTime(date, offset) {

        var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
       
        var serverdate  = new Date(date);
      
        var ISTOffset = 330;
  
        var tzDifference =  offset  * 60 + (ISTOffset + serverdate.getTimezoneOffset() );
        var offsetTime = new Date(serverdate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60000);

        return offsetTime.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  }
    
    console.log(convertToLocalTime('March 12 2019 11:30 pm', -8.00));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I am in IST (5.5 will be the offset). So **'March 12 2019 11:30 pm', -8.00** should be shown as **March 13 2019 12:00 pm**. But I am getting the time as **March 12, 2019, 10:00 AM**

Comment: I don't  fully understand what you want, but maybe my edit can help you a little more. Greetings

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of clarity. It want to convert **March 12 2019 11:30 pm PST** to my local time. For that if I use the function like this `convertToLocalTime('March 12 2019 11:30 pm', -8.00)`. The output I am getting is **March 12, 2019, 3:30 PM** which is not the correct date. It should be **March 13 2019 12:00 pm**.  I tried it with you update code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should invert the offset sign (negative to positive and vice versa)
2. On top of that, add your current timezone offset

   - `(-n)` to invert sign of number `n`
   - [`serverTime.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) will return time zone difference from UTC in minutes so you `/60` to get it to the same unit in hours.
   - You also invert the sign of the timezone offset in hours.

```js
function convertToLocalTime(date, offset) {
  const serverTime = new Date(date);
  const localOffset = ((-offset) + (-(serverTime.getTimezoneOffset() / 60))) * 3600000;
  const d = new Date(serverTime.getTime() + localOffset).toUTCString();
  return new Date(d);
}

let dt = convertToLocalTime('March 12 2019 11:30 pm', -8);
console.log(dt);
console.log(dt.toString());
```